# How can I take a list of dictionaries and split them up based on key values

Tags: python

just as the title says I wanted to know how to take the following code and split them up into separate lists.

```
x = [{'class': 'm', 'radius': 2}, {'class': 'b', 'radius': 5}, {'class': 'm', 'radius': 22}]
```

I want an outcome as such

```
m = [{'class': 'm', 'radius': 2}, {'class': 'm', 'radius': 22}]
b = [{'class': 'b', 'radius': 5}]
```

I wanted to use a for-loop but I am not sure how I could take the entire dictionary and not just specific keys of the dictionary.
Thank you!

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Comment: Is it only going to be `m` and `b`? Or can there be arbitrary classes? If the latter, you do *not* want individual variables, but a dict like `{'m': [...], 'b': [...]}`…!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for an elegant way to do this. However, you need to first sort your list of dicts by class.

```
import operator
import itertools

x.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('class'))
groups = itertools.groupby(x, key=operator.itemgetter('class'))

collected = dict((cls, list(items)) for cls, items in groups)
```

The `collected` line might not be necessary depending on your use case. `groupby` returns single-use iterators of grouped items, so here we convert them to a `list` so you can print them and iterate over them multiple times without confusing behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
m, b = [], []
for d in x:
  if d['class'] == 'm':
    m.append(d)
  else:
    b.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
m = [dict for dict in x if dict['class'] == 'm']
b = [dict for dict in x if dict['class'] == 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a generalised approach which will take all the unique classes and create a list of lists.

```
class_list=set([a['class'] for a in x])
new_list=[]
for clas in class_list:
    sub_list=[]
    for val in x:
        if val['class']==clas:
            sub_list.append(val)
    new_list.append(sub_list)
print(new_list)
```

You will get an output like this.

```
[[{'class': 'b', 'radius': 5}],
 [{'class': 'm', 'radius': 2}, {'class': 'm', 'radius': 22}]]
```